Setting cookies in middleware with written multilingual logic (next js app router 14)
There was a problem with access refresh token authorization. You need to make a request to refresh tokens and overwrite them in cookies. To apply the cookie change in the middleware, you need to:
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) { const response = NextResponse.next(); response.cookies.set('vercel', 'fast'); return response }
Explanation of the logic: returning a response in the Next.js middleware is necessary to apply changes to the original response, such as setting cookies, adding headers, or a redirect, which affects the client's behavior when receiving a response.
The problem arises in multilingualism, because I change the application url and do not return a response to apply the changes to the original response, that is, to apply the change of cookies
Code:
`export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
const response = NextResponse.next();
response.cookies.set('vercel', 'fast')
if (pathname.startsWith(/${defaultLocale}/) || pathname === /${defaultLocale}) {
return NextResponse.redirect(
new URL(
pathname.replace(
/${defaultLocale},
pathname === /${defaultLocale} ? '/' : '',
),
request.url,
),
);
}
const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
(locale) => !pathname.startsWith(/${locale}/) && pathname !== /${locale},
);
if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
return NextResponse.rewrite(
new URL(
/${defaultLocale}${pathname}${request.nextUrl.search},
request.nextUrl.href,
),
);
}
return response;
}
export const config = { matcher: '/((?!.\.).)' };`
Help us implement cookies without losing the logic of multilingualism
Optional: maybe you have an example code with access refresh tokens, where the logic is on the server side + how to authorize the request on the server side
Here is a link to the next js project with middleware: https://github.com/rendrdotio/i18n-basics-video
Thank you very much!!!
I did not find any answer and studied the documentation in detail to solve this problem: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware
